# Merging a rebased branch into the un-rebased version of it

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I have a branch FEATURE that was split from MAIN about a year ago, and has some extra features.

I have created a new branch MY-FEATURE from the FEATURE branch.

I have rebased MY-FEATURE branch to the latest MAIN branch, and I discarded a commit, where MAIN was merged into FEATURE about 6 months ago.

What's the best way to now make the remote FEATURE Branch same as the MY-FEATURE branch?

Would merging MY-FEATURE into FEATURE do the trick? It feels like I may start getting into a world of pain, especially since I discarded a merge commit during the rebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the `FEATURE` branch to point to the `MY-FEATURE` branch, you may simply hard reset the former to the latter:

```
# from FEATURE
git reset --hard MY-FEATURE
# force push, if you like
git push --force FEATURE
```

Note that a force push of `FEATURE` to the remote would be necessary here, as its history has been rewritten.  You should probably avoid doing this if `FEATURE` be in use by other people.

Comment: "You should probably avoid this if FEATURE is in use by other people.": agreed, although alternatively, @TeabagD, communicate well with your team and tell them all you're going to force push FEATURE, and ask them all to make sure they work from the new branch and not the old one from that point on.